# How can I find the distance between two parallel lines that are in vector form?

Tags: vectors

I have a question to do, and I keep getting the answer wrong.

I need to know the distance between these parallel lines:

L1: [x,y,z] = [1, 3,-4] + s[2,-5,2]

L2: [x,y,z] = [4, 0, 2] + t[2,-5,2]

The answer is 4.58, but I have no idea how to get that.

Thank you to everyone in advance.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your work? One way to approach this is to find the normal/perpendicular direction to the first line, construct a line through the origin going in that direction, determine its intersections with $L_1$ and $L_2$ and then calculate the distance between those two points. If you provide us with the way you tried to solve this, we might be able to correct your mistake for your chosen method.

Comment: See here http://www.nabla.hr/PC-LinePlaneIn3DSpC5.htm

Comment: answer is $\sqrt{21}$

Answer (score 0):

The formula for distance between parallel lines in $3D$ is $$\frac{|\vec b ×(\vec a_{2}-\vec a_{1})|}{|\vec b|}$$ where $L_1=\vec a_1+\lambda \vec b,L2=\vec a_2+\lambda \vec b$ can you continue from here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $A=(1,3,-4)$ and $B=(4,0,2)$, $\vec p=(2,-5,2)$ and $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec AB$ and $\vec p$, then the required distance is $|\vec{AB}\sin\theta|$.

Use cross product.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't remember a fancy distance formula, you could solve the old-fashioned way:

minimize the distance between $(4,0,2)+t(2,-5,2)=(4+2t,-5t,2+2t)$ and $(1,3,-4).$

The distance squared is $(3+2t)^2+(3+5t)^2+(6+2t)^2=33t^2+66t+54,$

which has its minimum when $66t=-66$, i.e., $t=-1$,

so the distance squared is $33(-1)^2+66(-1)+54=21.$

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the lines is measured perpendicularly to them. So, pick a point on each line and project the segment joining them onto a plane perpendicular to them. The distance between the lines is equal to the length of the segment’s projection.